# For what $z$ do $\Gamma(x)$ and $x^ze^{-x}$ share a tangent line at exactly one point?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

The motivation for this question is that $\Gamma(x)$ is defined as $\int_0^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$. When plotting both $y=\Gamma(x)$ and $y=x^ze^{-x}$ for different values of $z,$ the two functions "kiss," *i.e.* they share a tangent line at exactly one point, at a value around $z=2.88518212.$ What is this number exactly? Does it have a closed form? What is the slope of the tangent line at said "kissing point?"

Comment: It is often not easy to give a closed form for that $z$ as $z$ is characterized by transcendental equations (i.e. $\Gamma(x)=x^ze^{-x}$ and $\Gamma'(x)=e^{-x}(zx^{z-1}-x^z)$).

Comment: So $z = \frac{\ln \Gamma(x_0) + x_0}{\ln x_0}$ where $x_0$ is the unique real solution  of the equation $F'(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln x}$ on $(1, \infty)$ where $F(x) = \ln(\ln \Gamma(x) + x)$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks, River, that seems to be correct. How did you get that result?

Comment: @JodiSpitz See TravorLZH's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two equations to be solved are
$$\Gamma (x)-x^z\, e^{-x} =0 \tag 1$$
$$e^{-x} (x-z) x^{z-1}+\Gamma (x) \,\psi (x) =0 \tag 2$$

$$(1)\qquad \implies\qquad \color{red}{z(x)=\frac{\log \left( \Gamma (x)\right)+x}{\log (x)}}\tag 3$$ Plug in $(2)$ to obtain
$$\Gamma (x) \left(\psi (x)-\frac{\log \left(e^x \Gamma (x)\right)}{x \log
   (x)}+1\right)=0\tag 4$$

Finally, the equation to be solved is
$$x \log (x) (1+\psi (x))-(x+\log (\Gamma (x)))=0\tag 5$$ The solution of $(5)$ is close to $x_0=2$. The first iterate of Newton method gives
$$x_1=\frac{2 \left(3+\left(\pi ^2-6\right) \log (2)\right)}{\left(\pi ^2-3 \gamma
   \right) \log (2)}$$ which, numerically, gives
$$z(x_1)=\color{red}{2.8851821}313\cdots$$ to be compared to the exact solution
$$z=     \color{red}{2.8851821225\cdots}$$

Trying to find a good approximation of the solution of $(5)$ in terms of basic constants
$$x\sim -\frac{1+4 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{3}-4 e+\pi  (3+\pi )-3 \log (3)+3\log (2)}{3-3
   \sqrt{2}-8 e+2 (\pi -2) \pi +6\log (2)+2\log(3)}$$ whose error is $4.13\times 10^{-19}$.

This value gives
$$z=\color{red}{2.885182122499993175519796224373851235}306\cdots$$
to be compared to the exact solution
$$z=\color{red}{2.885182122499993175519796224373851235141\cdots}$$

Comment: The decimal expansion of this number is one of the few on OEIS that contain the sequence "3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9" by pure coincidence (that is, without any relation to pi): https://oeis.org/A359699